# Update Each Group with Random Values (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

How do I update the column `Code` for each group? I'd like to randomly assign one of the following codes to each group: AD, CD, FA

```
+-------------------
|GroupId| Code    |
+------------------+
|    1  | AD       | 
|    1  | AD       |
|    1  | AD       | 
|    2  | CD       |
|    2  | CD       |
|    3  | FA       |
+------------------+
```

Speed isn't an issue as this will just be test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (GroupID int, Code char(2))
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (GroupID)
VALUES (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(6),(7),(7),(7),(7),(8),(8),(9);
GO
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupID, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 3 AS RandInt
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE YT
SET YT.Code = V.Code
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Groups G ON YT.GroupID = G.GroupID
     JOIN (VALUES(0,'AD'),
                 (1,'CD'),
                 (2,'FA')) V(I,Code) ON V.I = G.RandInt
WHERE YT.Code IS NULL; --Is this needed?
GO
SELECT GroupID,
       Code
FROM dbo.YourTable;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f38c2199ef710b0fe10719f2b13c0d3c)

If you have a table with your distinct values for `GroupID` this would be more performant.